# React children are mutating parent state through props...I am unclear as to the cause

Tags: object, reactjs, properties, state, children

I have a React component that is passing an object to a child element containing an input field to be modified via a passed function.  The input field is changing the state of the child element but somehow, without invoking the passed function, the props object is being modified.

this is the render function of the parent class:

```
render: function() {
    const newTriggerClass = this.state.item.triggerID === ""
        ? " new-trigger"
        : "";
    return (
        <div className={newTriggerClass}>
            <div className="triggers-detail">

                <section className="trigger-info group">
                    <TriggerInfoEntry
                    item={this.state.item}
                    triggerState={this.state.editTriggerState}
                    columnHeaders={this.props.columnHeaders}
                    hideDetail={this.hideDetail}
                    editAction={this.props.editAction}
                    editToggle={this.editToggle}
                    _onChange={this._onInfoChange}
                    createAction={this.props.createAction}
                    deleteAction={this.props.deleteAction}/>
                </section>

                <section className="trigger-actions group">
                    <TriggerActionEntry
                    item={this.state.item}
                    actionState={this.state.editActionState}
                    editToggle={this.editToggle}
                    editAction={this.editTriggerAction}
                    actionIndex={this.state.selectedActionIndex}/>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div className={"modal-overlay" + newTriggerClass}>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
},
```

and the child `TriggerActionEntry` is setting it's own `state.item` to a clone of `props.item`.

```
propTypes: {
    item: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    editAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    editToggle: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    actionState: React.PropTypes.bool
},

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        item: assign({testy: true}, this.props.item),
        actionIndex: 0,
        deleteState: false,
        editState: false
    };
},
```

when I change the state of the child component (state.item) through an input, the parent state gets changed!  I am not sure of the cause. Nothing that I have read online alludes to this behavior.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
@garrettmaring The code I use to change state is only designed to work on the child state which is set in the getInitialState as a clone of `this.props.item` through `assign` which is my alias for `object-assign` which is an `Object.assign` ponyfill.  The form to change `item` is actually one more child down.  Here is the render of `TriggerActionEntry`

```
<div>
                    <TriggerActionForm
                    action={this.state.item.actions[this.state.actionIndex]}
                    index={this.state.actionIndex}
                    addNewAction={this.addNewAction}
                    editTriggerAction={this.editTriggerAction}
                    deleteTriggerAction={this.deleteTriggerAction}
                    editState={this.state.editState}
                    deleteState={this.props.actionState}
                    toggleEdit={this.toggleEdit}
                    activateEdit={this.activateEdit}/>
 </div>
```

and here is the _onChange function of the grandchild `TriggerActionForm`

```
_onChange: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newAction = assign({}, this.state.action);
    const keyname = e.currentTarget.dataset.keyname;
    if (keyname === "minDelay") {
        newAction[keyname] = e.currentTarget.value;
    } else {
        newAction.args[keyname] = e.currentTarget.value;
    }
    this.setState({action: newAction});
    if (!this.props.editState) {
        this.props.activateEdit();
    }
},
```

even when I unmount that component, the TriggerActionEntry `state.item` is modified, and shows up in the modified state when the component is mounted again...

UPDATE 2:  OK, the problem is that neither `Object.assign` nor `object-assign` deeply clones objects.  The classic!  The actions were objects that were nested within `item` and rather than being cloned, another reference to the nested object was being created.  Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried `Object.assign({}, {testy: true}, this.props.item)` in the `getInitialState` function? Or creating a clone of `this.state.item` before passing it down. This seems to be a reference issue. That is, even though you use assign in `getInitialState`, item in the sub component is still holding a reference to the `state.item` in the parent component.

Comment: @suntruth show us the code that you use `setState` on the child element. It seems that you're changing a property of the object, and if that's true, it's the same object reference the father element has, so it will change as well. If you want to set a new state to the item, you should completely create a new object when using `setState`, by using assign not only for the item, but for the entire object as well.

Comment: @garrettmaring, I added more detail to the question.  Thanks for the responses

Comment: I will try doing the cloning outside of getInitialState to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im currently working on the same thing . The parent pass the data as a props to the children function. (im using hook instead of class). The purpose of the child component to process the data given from the parent and export as pdf or excel. Imagine the data pass in as an object that consists multiple array of objects . Each child object have an element of proj id which i would like to remove. The moment the data pass in , i have this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Beq6.png)

i set state with the data pass in from parent. When i gone throught some process and remove the the projid. When i try to access with any elements in the parent function. the whole thing gone broken.